# Flask executes function even though it is never called in code (only defined)

Tags: python, function, flask, pycharm

Looking at the "hello world" example code for Flask (just started using it), it goes:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    return 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run it (in Pycharm) and go to local host in my browser, it displays "Hello".

However the function is never called in the code, only defined, so I don't understand why it's being executed.

Comment: You have returned `hello` for a route `/`. When you will visit the page with route `/` the function will be called itself. This is how flask works.

Comment: @charchit, so functions are never explicitly called in Flask?

Comment: yes the [views](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+are+views+in+flask&oq=what+are+views+in+flask&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j0i22i30l6.11561j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are never called explicitly, but if you have a function that does some processing on the data recieved means the function not a `view` it has to be called explicitly .

Comment: @charchit Thank you that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the page in your browser, or using some sort of HTTP request client. You are visiting the `root` which is `/`.

Here, you have defined a route: `@app.route('/')`, which points to the function `hello_world`.

This function is being called, because you are visiting `/` when you visit the page, i.e. the root.

If you went to `host:port/randomroute`, you would get a 404, because no route is defined for this.

Comment: But why is the function being executed even though I've done nothing beyond defining it?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff The function is being executed because you are calling it by visiting that route. That is the basic functionality of how Flask works, I would highly advise reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks I will, I assumed it worked just like Python

Comment: @jeremyradcliff No worries, the concept of routing and web frameworks can be a bit confusing when you're first getting started!

Comment: Haha yeah, it's embarrassing but I know nothing about web stuff and I'm supposed to do a full stack app for work. I guess it's the perfect opportunity to learn!

Comment: Good luck :) Flask is quite fun to work with once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you, I believe it :)